# Using BTYD to predict date and amount of customer's next purchase

Tags: r, machine-learning

The BTYD package in R looks very useful for predicting future customer behavior based on past transactions.

However, the [walk-through](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf) only illustrates predicting how many transactions a customer will make in an upcoming period, for example in the next year or month.

Is there a way to use this package to create a prediction for the date on which a customer will purchase, and the expected amount of the purchase?

For example, using the sample data set available in the BTYD package:

```
cdnowElog <- system.file("data/cdnowElog.csv", package = "BTYD")
elog <- dc.ReadLines(cdnowElog, cust.idx = 2,
                     date.idx = 3, sales.idx = 5)
# Change to date format
elog$date <- as.Date(elog$date, "%Y%m%d");
elog[1:3,]

#   cust       date sales
# 1    1 1997-01-01 29.33
# 2    1 1997-01-18 29.73
# 3    1 1997-08-02 14.96
```

I would want an output that has the customer number, expected next date of purchase, and expected purchase amount.

```
# cust   exp_date   exp_sales
# 1    1998-02-23   19.35
# 2    1997-09-12   39.83
# 3    1998-01-05   24.56
```

Or this package can only predict the expected number of transactions in a time period, not the date itself or the spend amount?  Is there a better approach for what I want to achieve?

I apologize if this question seems very basic, but I couldn't find the answer to this conceptual question in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/BTYD.pdf).